# I don't need 'view' page for my custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy. I don't link to the taxonomy on the page but from the admin anyone can visit the taxonomy/term url and the unstyled list page will be visible. How can I force wp to not use the default layout (index.php) for that listing? What's the best method? For example I creat a taxonomy template and I redirect it to the front page?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to "turn off" the public facing part of a taxonomy (eg. just use it for grouping), you can do that when you [register it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Just set the `query_var` argument to `false` and WordPress will not recognize taxonomy page requests and simply 404. This will work if you don't have pretty permalinks enabled.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse94193_register');
function wpse94193_register()
{
    register_taxonomy('your_taxonomy', 'your_post_type', array(
        // other stuff here...
        'query_var' => false,
    ));
}
```

You can also disable pretty permalinks by setting the `rewrite` argument to false (props [otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto)).

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse94193_register');
function wpse94193_register()
{
    register_taxonomy('your_taxonomy', 'your_post_type', array(
        // other stuff here...
        'rewrite'   => false,
        'query_var' => false,
    ));
}
```

If you do need to allow logged in users to view the taxonomy pages (can't tell from the question), that's  different story.

Comment: This. Also, set the `rewrite` arg to false as well to disable the permalinks for them too.

Comment: setting `query_var` to false only works when pretty permalinks aren't enabled, you need the `rewrite` argument as well to cover all bases. deleting my answer and upvoting yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display). If your custom taxonomy is called `custom_taxonomy`, you should be able to create a template file called `taxonomy-custom_taxonomy.php`, and it could contain, for instance:

```
<?php
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;  // stop processing since we're redirecting
?>
```

(See the [Codex page for `wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) for more on redirecting in WordPress.)

Comment: Yes it was my idea too, what to you think is it the best method?

Comment: I'd say go with @chrisguitarguy's method -- set the `rewrite` and `query_var` to false.  My way will work, but his way looks like it's the proper WordPress way to do it.